# Let $a,b,n$ be positive integers, if $n|a^n-b^n$ then $n|\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a,b,n$ be positive integers, if $n|a^n-b^n$ then prove that $n|\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$.

---

My approach: If $n$ is a prime, write $n=p$, then since $$a^p\equiv b^p\pmod p$$
and by Fermat's little theorem, we have $$a^p\equiv a, b^p\equiv b\pmod p.$$
Therefore $$a\equiv b\pmod p.$$
We have $$\dfrac{a^p-b^p}{a-b}\equiv a^{p-1}+a^{p-2}b+\cdots+b^{p-1}\equiv pa^{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod p,$$
so this statement is true for prime $n$. 
But when $n$ is not a prime, I cannot construct a similar proof.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(n, a-b)=d$ is the highest common factor. Use the $a=b+kd$ and the binomial expansion to show that $d^2|a^n-b^n$.

Comment: After that, how can I show $d^2|a^n-b^n$ implies $n|(a^n-b^n)/(a-b)$?

Comment: @kelvinhong方 You asked for a suggestion, so I made one. You want to show that $n(a-b)$ is a factor of $a^n-b^n$. If $n=cd$ and $a-b=de$ this amounts to showing that $cd^2e$ is a factor where $c$ and $e$ are coprime. $d^2$ and $de$ are done (note your polynomial factorisation: beware that $d$ and $e$ may still have a common factor), and you are given $cd$.  The question then is whether you can put the pieces together.

Comment: thank you, I will think a bit more about this.